# PyMuPDF: AttributeError: module 'fitz' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, pymupdf

`pip3 install PyMuPDF`

```
Collecting PyMuPDF Using cached PyMuPDF-1.18.17-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (5.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: PyMuPDF
Successfully installed PyMuPDF-1.18.17
```

```
import fitz
doc = fitz.open("my_pdf.pdf")
```

When I look for `def open` on the `fitz.py` file, I find nothing.
So I understand the error But I don't understand why the file that I download doesn't have this function ? Can someone share the good files please ? Or maybe I missed something else ?

FULL TRACE:

```
runfile('D:/Documents/Python_projects/Point_and_area_pdf_to_excel/get_info.py', wdir='D:/Documents/Python_projects/Point_and_area_pdf_to_excel')
Reloaded modules: six, dateutil._common, dateutil.relativedelta, dateutil.tz._common, dateutil.tz._factories, dateutil.tz.win, dateutil.tz.tz, dateutil.tz, dateutil.parser._parser, dateutil.parser.isoparser, dateutil.parser, chardet.enums, chardet.charsetprober, chardet.charsetgroupprober, chardet.codingstatemachine, chardet.escsm, chardet.escprober, chardet.latin1prober, chardet.mbcssm, chardet.utf8prober, chardet.mbcharsetprober, chardet.euctwfreq, chardet.euckrfreq, chardet.gb2312freq, chardet.big5freq, chardet.jisfreq, chardet.chardistribution, chardet.jpcntx, chardet.sjisprober, chardet.eucjpprober, chardet.gb2312prober, chardet.euckrprober, chardet.cp949prober, chardet.big5prober, chardet.euctwprober, chardet.mbcsgroupprober, chardet.hebrewprober, chardet.sbcharsetprober, chardet.langbulgarianmodel, chardet.langgreekmodel, chardet.langhebrewmodel, chardet.langrussianmodel, chardet.langthaimodel, chardet.langturkishmodel, chardet.sbcsgroupprober, chardet.universaldetector, chardet.version, chardet
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Documents\Python_projects\Point_and_area_pdf_to_excel\get_info.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(get_dict_list(path))

  File "D:\Documents\Python_projects\Point_and_area_pdf_to_excel\get_info.py", line 7, in get_dict_list
    text_list = get_pdf_page_text_list(pdf_path)

  File "D:\Documents\Python_projects\Point_and_area_pdf_to_excel\get_info.py", line 19, in get_pdf_page_text_list
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)

AttributeError: module 'fitz' has no attribute 'open'
```

Comment: Can you post the error and the trace?

Comment: That's what you needed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely to be an installation issue and looks like there already exists a package `fitz` installed on your environment and is unrelated to `PyMuPDF`.

So when `PyMuPDF` calls `fitz` it might actually be calling the wrong `fitz` package.

You can consider doing a clean install of all dependencies or create a virtual environment to work with `PyMuPDF`.

You can also try rolling back `fitz` to version `1.16.14`

Comment: I think it's this one. I couldn't resolve the problem on my Spyder env, too complicated. I passed on a PyCharm env and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 16):

Uninstall and reinstall pyMuPDF.

this error usually indicates that **init**.py wasn't executed. Which e.g. happens when you are in the installation fitz directory and start python.

```
> pip uninstall PyMuPDF
Found existing installation: PyMuPDF 1.18.17
Uninstalling PyMuPDF-1.18.17:
  Would remove:
    /home/deerawj/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyMuPDF-1.18.17.dist-info/*
    /home/deerawj/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fitz/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled PyMuPDF-1.18.17

> pip install PyMuPDF
Collecting PyMuPDF
  Downloading PyMuPDF-1.18.17-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (6.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.4 MB 62 kB/s
Installing collected packages: PyMuPDF
Successfully installed PyMuPDF-1.18.17
```

Also check out,
https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/660

Answer (score 8):

I also ran into the same issue. Had to remove the Fitz, which was a different package than the one PyMuPdf calls. Then even after uninstalling the Fitz and installing pymupdf the same error was coming.
This is what worked for me.

```py
pip uninstall fitz
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pymupdf
```

Comment: Just running `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pymupdf` was enough for me.